# JavaScript - setInterval / setTimeout & clearInterval, wont execute properly

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

If I `"body onload="varname=setInterval etc, etc""` then I end up with two `setInterval` events running at once, if I get to `"overload == true"` it doesent reset the `ketchCount` and it doesent update the picture from the array, it just starts the `setInterval` and works from there. I know im pretty newby, but I would appreciate any help!

```
ketchupArray=new Array();
ketchupArray[0] = new Image(192, 168);
ketchupArray[0].src = "./pictures/levels/nothing.jpg?";
ketchupArray[1] = new Image(192, 168);
ketchupArray[1].src = "./pictures/levels/lowest.jpg?";
ketchupArray[2] = new Image(192, 168);
ketchupArray[2].src = "./pictures/levels/low.jpg?";
ketchupArray[3] = new Image(192, 168);
ketchupArray[3].src = "./pictures/levels/medium.jpg?";
ketchupArray[4] = new Image(192, 168);
ketchupArray[4].src = "./pictures/levels/high.jpg?";
ketchupArray[5] = new Image(192, 168);
ketchupArray[5].src = "./pictures/levels/highest.jpg?";

overload = false;
ketchCount = 0;
var lessCount;
var overCount;
var lessCountVar;

function overFunction()
{
overload == false;
ketchCount == 0;
document.getElementById("ketchupLevel").src = ketchupArray[ketchCount].src;
lessCountVar=setInterval(function(){lessCount()},5000);
}

function lessCount()
{
if (ketchCount == 0)
  {
  return;
  }
ketchCount--;
document.getElementById("ketchupLevel").src = ketchupArray[ketchCount].src;
}

function moreKetchup()
{
if (overload == true) 
  {
  return;
  }
ketchCount++;
document.getElementById("ketchupLevel").src = ketchupArray[ketchCount].src;
if (ketchCount == 5)
  {
  overload == true;
  clearInterval(lessCountVar);
  overCount=setTimeout(function(){overFunction()},5000);
  }
}

function lessKetchup()
{
if (overload == true)
  {
  return;
  }
else if (ketchCount == 0)
  {
  return;
  }
ketchCount--;
document.getElementById("ketchupLevel").src = ketchupArray[ketchCount].src;
}
```

Comment: today i read about it. may be this one helps you.http://www.adequatelygood.com/2011/4/Replacing-setTimeout-Globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you may try:

in `onload` use `setTimeout()` to start `overFunction()` for the first time.

in `overFunction()` you probably have error in your code. You are comparing overload and ketchCount instead assigning values to them. The correct code should look more like

```
function overFunction()
{
  overload = false;
  ketchCount = 0;
  document.getElementById("ketchupLevel").src = ketchupArray[ketchCount].src;
  lessCountVar=setInterval(function(){lessCount()},5000);
}
```

Comment: You are quite literally my hero. Thank you so much.

Im going to go google the explanation to "comparing" and "assigning" and why which is which, and how I did that wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: Assignment means that you are setting the value of a variable. Comparing is when you compare two values whether or not they are equal of different.